# for loop taking too long to produce/export output in Python

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, for-loop, output

This question is a continuation of a previous question [for loop taking too long to produce output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41339200/for-loop-taking-too-long-to-produce-output?noredirect=1#comment69881316_41339200) that I asked earlier today. As advised to me in one comment, I used `pandas` for reading excel files in place of `xlrd`. Here is the program that I wrote -

```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np

   no_of_columns = 10000

   Book1 = pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book1.xlsx",header=None,name=range(no_of_columns))
   Book2 = pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book2.xlsx",header=None,name=range(no_of_columns))
   Book3 = pd.read_excel("D:\Python\Book3.xlsx",header=None,name=range(no_of_columns))


   for i in range(1,11001):
      for j in range(0,10000):
         if Book1.iloc[i,j] == 100 and Book2.iloc[i,j] == 150 and Book3.iloc[i,j] == 150:
            print 1
         else:
            print 0
```

But this also didn't solved the problems that I am having. The program is still running (it has been 5 hours) and the text output that I am exporting in my directory is still of size 0 bytes. Again, is there anything wrong with the program? Why am I getting a file whose size has been the same since the beginning of the execution? I have ran such kind of large loops on **R** but each time I started to export my output in text or in excel format, I get a file in my directory whose size continues to increase as the loop progresses. So why this isn't happening here? What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

Assuming all books are same size

```
(Book1.eq(100) & Book2.eq(150) & Book3.eq(150)) * 1
```

---

Response to comment:

I wrote this for aesthetics as well.  To replicate what you've done and get results to a csv, I'd do this:

```
(Book1.eq(100) & Book2.eq(150) & Book3.eq(150)).stack().mul(1) \
    .to_csv('filename.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: very elegant solution!

Comment: Am I suppose to replace the `if` command with the command that you suggested? Or should I add this somewhere?

Comment: @Dark_Knight After defining `Book1`, `Book2`, and `Book3`, either run this or assign it to a variable (say `df`).  I'm assuming you don't really want to print each thing out to the screen.  Then if you need to access any value then its `df.iloc[i, j]`

Comment: Thanks! and no, I don't want anything on screen. I just want a text file which contains all the 1's and 0's. And I want an output which has only one column in the manner as the loop went(Comparing first row all columns, then second row all columns, then third and so on). So, does this command will give me the same result?

Comment: @piRSquared Hello again! I tried what you suggested but still the program ran continuously for 10 hours and I didn't get any output. This time, in fact no csv file was created in the directory.